# Calculating sum between date intervals mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the sum of values between two dates in this case I would always want to keep one date static.  Example finding the value between dates April to July, keeping April static, so therefore another case could be sum of values between dates April to May, again keeping april static. I have been working on several queries for quite sometime but havn't been sucessful in doing so could you have a look at the following SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad042/8) and aid me please I would really appreciate the help

Comment: What is all that case stuff? Why not just `SUM(column) WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-06-01'`?

Comment: I am trying to write the SUM(column) WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-06-01' using a case as I have in the previous ones

Comment: Then write that. `SUM(CASE WHEN datecolumn BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-06-01' THEN valuecolumn ELSE 0 END)`, will add only the values from rows between those dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just add another `CASE` statement:

```
sum(case when pay_date between '2012-04-01' and '2012-06-01'
        then amount end) range_amount
```

so your query would be:

```
SELECT p.name,
       v.v_name,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN MONTH(py.pay_date) = 4 THEN amount
           end) april_amount,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN MONTH(py.pay_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN amount
           end) current_month_amount,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN MONTH(py.pay_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 THEN amount
           end) previous_month_amount,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN pay_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-06-01' THEN amount
           end) range_amount
FROM   persons p
       LEFT JOIN vehicle v
              ON p.id = v.person_veh
       LEFT JOIN payment py
              ON p.id = py.person_id
GROUP  BY p.name,
          v.v_name
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad042/14)

Then if you want to change the date range, you can pass in a value for the end date and make that a variable.

Comment: sorry an accident Im so sorry my internet connection is bad and i think I was clicking before the page was completely refreshed

Comment: unless it wasn't me, I don't recall downvoting your answer, thats bads sportsmanship